# Как сделать scroll для цены, как на сайте розетки(интернет-магазин)?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать scroll для цены, как на сайте розетки(интернет-магазин)? Желательно на 
html + css + (php или javascript)

Comment: Какой скролл, там просто цена на желтом фоне? Уточните свой вопрос, а то тут гадать можно долго

Comment: Какие розетки? где ссылка??